# Emacs HTML in Javascript template string literals - how?

Tags: javascript, emacs, syntax-highlighting, indentation

i spent quite some time to configure Emacs for web development,
watched tons of tutorials and even wrote some Emacs Lisp.

In my Javascript code, I heavily rely on **HTML in template string literals**
and this is the one thing that for the life of me cannot get to work.
In web-mode the template string lietarals are recognized as such and
placeholders are syntax highlighted, but the HTML is only a string.

I currently use **web-mode** and **lsp-mode with the Typescript server** for syntax-highlighting and indenting (plus company, flycheck, vertico, consult, ...), but that is not carved in stone.

I would very much appreciate, if someone could point out a solution
to this. Maybe a pointer to a working .emacs?

Here is a stripped down example how it currently looks:

[image: Example Code]

Best Wishes!

Marc